# undefined reference to `MurmurHash3_x64_128(void const*, int, unsigned int, void*)'

Tags: c++, bloom-filter

I am trying to code a C++ implementation of a Bloom filter using the MurmurHash3 hash function. My implementation is based on this site: http://blog.michaelschmatz.com/2016/04/11/how-to-write-a-bloom-filter-cpp/

Somehow, in my BloomFilter header file, the hash function throws an incomplete type error, also, when I use the hash function inside of the add function, I get an erroe- undefined reference to `MurmurHash3_x64_128(void const*, int, unsigned int, void*)'.I am wondering how to fix this. Futhermore, I am familiar with C++ but I am wondering how I would pass the data within a file as a parameter to this object. Should I read each line of the file store in an array and pass the array to the object memebers parameter?

My code is:

```
#ifndef BLOOM_FILTER_H
#define BLOOM_FILTER_H
#include "MurmurHash3.h"
#include <vector>
#include <array>


//basic structure of a bloom filter object
struct BloomFilter {
BloomFilter(size_t size, uint8_t numHashes);
void add(const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len);
bool possiblyContains(const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len) const;
private:
uint8_t m_numHashes;
std::vector<bool> m_bits;
};
//Bloom filter constructor
BloomFilter::BloomFilter(size_t size, uint8_t numHashes)
: m_bits(size),
m_numHashes(numHashes) {}
//Hash array created using the MurmurHash3 code
static std::array<uint64_t, 2> myhash(const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len)
{
std::array<uint64_t, 2> hashValue;
MurmurHash3_x64_128(data, len, 0, hashValue.data());
return hashValue;
}
//Hash array created using the MurmurHash3 code
inline size_t nthHash(int n,
uint64_t hashA,
uint64_t hashB,
size_t filterSize) {
return (hashA + n * hashB) % filterSize; // <- not sure if that is OK, 
perhaps it is.
}
//Adds an element to the array
void BloomFilter::add(const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len) {
auto hashValues = myhash(data, len);
for (int n = 0; n < m_numHashes; n++)
{
    m_bits[nthHash(n, hashValues[0], hashValues[1], m_bits.size())] = true;
}
}
//Returns true or false based on a probabilistic assesment of the array         
using MurmurHash3
bool BloomFilter::possiblyContains(const uint8_t *data, std::size_t   len) 
const {
auto hashValues = myhash(data, len);
for (int n = 0; n < m_numHashes; n++)
{
    if (!m_bits[nthHash(n, hashValues[0], hashValues[1], m_bits.size())])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
#endif
```

Comment: You can find the implementation of MurmurHash here: https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/tree/master/src

Comment: I have looked into the implementation code sir. I thought there was a linking problem so I specified the path in full yet I get the same error- undefined reference to `MurmurHash3_x64_128(void const*, int, unsigned int, void*)'

Comment: You have to compile MurmurHash3.cpp as well as including the header file. Add MurmurHash3.cpp to your project.

Comment: Actually MurmurHash3.cpp was giving an undefined WinMain error. But I included a main function and now it works. Thanks!